# How to open silverlight childwindow as separate browser

Tags: silverlight-4.0

when click on any button it should show the silverlight childwindow as a popup but insteadof modal popup i want to open child window as separate window/browser with the url

Comment: What exactly are you tying to achieve? Is this window part of your application or a completely separate application?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
  HtmlPopupWindowOptions options = new HtmlPopupWindowOptions();
  HtmlPage.PopupWindow(new Uri(http://localhost:51327/MyprintPage.aspx), "_newWindow", options);
```

Comment: This will open a whole new instance of Silverlight.

Comment: Yes.If the child window inside the application we can do something like this                                      HtmlPage.PopupWindow(new Uri(http://localhost:51327/MyprintPage.aspx), "_newWindow", options);